# How to list all users in the mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, command, mongo-shell

In the MongoDB shell, how do I list all users for the current database that I'm using?
I can't seem to find it anywhere on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can do:

```
db.getUsers()
```

or

```
show users
```

The both commands print a list of users for the current database. See MongoDB documentation for [User Management](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-user-management/).

Comment: > db.getUsers();
2018-02-27T06:45:45.853+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not authorized on test  to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0 } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1523:1
@(shell):1:1

> show users;
2018-02-27T06:46:57.428+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: not authorized on test to execute command...

Comment: @flik Maybe you need to reset your mongodb users

Comment: I'd like to leave here a comment from @flik: "It is fixed with: `show roles;` then added the role from list."

Comment: To list users in another database: `db.getSiblingDB('admin').getUsers()`.

Answer (score 5):

**List belongs to DB users:**

`use db_name` and `db.getUsers()` or `show users`

**List according to the authentication type:**

```
db.getUsers({ filter: { mechanisms: "SCRAM-SHA-256" } })
```

**List with the credentials:**

```
db.getUsers( {showCredentials: true,  filter: { mechanisms: "SCRAM-SHA-256" }} )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you like to list only user names and leave all other bulk info.. try

```
db.system.users.find({}, {"_id" : 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Following command can be used to get lis of user on a selected database.

**By using find on a selected db**

```
use admin;
db.system.users.find({}, {"user": 1, "db": 1, "roles": 1});
```

**To Get all the user on all the db**

```
db.getUsers();

or 

show users;
```

here you can get only user, db and roles nodes in response JSON.